# JavaMail attachment and body issue

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using below code to attach a pdf file to mail (JAVAMAIL). this postion works perfectly and adds attachment to my mail but this mail does not have any body.

```
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        msg.setContent(multipart);
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(pdf);
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(pdf.getName().toString());
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        msg.setContent(multipart);
```

when i add below lines to my code it removes attachment and send me mail containing the text only.

```
msg.setText(body);
```

please help me to add both attachment and test body to my mail.

Comment: I'd guess you should find some kind of TextBodyPart and call multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart). Can't really look that up right now, hth anyways

Comment: yes i did it. i just have to add new bodyparts. thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that if you want to send a message with attachments, then you need to have a part for your message, and a part for your attachment.

By calling `setText` in the message, you are throwing away the multipart you set earlier.

Your message needs to have an hierarchy that looks like this (more nesting is necessary if you want to have a plain text and html message):

```
MimeMessage
+- MimeMultiPart
   +- MimeBodyPart (message)
   +- MimeBodyPart (attachment)
```

For example

```java
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
MimeMultiPart multiPart = new MimeMultiPart();

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setText(body);
multiPart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
attachment.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setFileName(pdf.getName().toString());
multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);

message.setContent(multiPart);
```

Comment: yes i have configured it by rob's comment. but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @ShariarImtiaz Yes, typing a full answer always takes more time than a quick comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have added below lines to make it work.

```
 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(pdf);
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(pdf.getName().toString());
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            htmlPart.setContent(body, "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
```

Comment: Some tips: add the html part before the attachment (it is not strictly necessary, but some mail clients might get confused), and use `htmlPart.setText(body, "UTF-8", "html")` instead of `setContent(body, "text/html")`.